Drag and drop not working in file-roller (24.04)
Drag and drop not working in file-roller
When I open a compressed file in file-roller, I can't drag and drop to extract a specific file, the dragging animation doesn't even happen.
I downgraded to version 43, (the version installed by default is 44), the animation of dragging the file happens, but when dropping it, the file is not extracted.
From my research, I saw that it is a typical Wayland problem, but in my case I am using X11.

Try the nemo file manager. Does drag-and-drop work there?

Are you sure the app you are trying to use has been updated to work with Ubuntu 24.04? Check with the maker of the tool.

@ArchismanPanigrahi, with nemo file manager, the drag and drop of file-roller works normally, but I wouldn't like use another file manager just to do this.

@David the file-roller was installed from Ubuntu official repository through sudo apt install file-roller, that install the 44.1 version, this version has this issue, but the 43.0-1 the default to Ubuntu 23.10 not.

GNOME team keeps removing (sometimes useful) features which does not align with their roadmaps. In most cases, there is no workaround either.
An workaround is to install a different file manager, like Nemo, which is the default file manager for Cinnamon, and is maintained by the Linux Mint team.
sudo apt install nemo


Can someone explain the downvote? Why is this answer not useful?
